# How to check whether field exists in symfony2 form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, field

Using this [manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html), I added dynamic field to my form. Now, how can I check existence of this field in my template?

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_errors(form) }}

  {% if ??? %}     <---------------------------
    {{ form_row(form.myDynamicField) }}
  {% endif %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What about,

```
{% if form.myDynamicField is defined %}
    {{ form_row(form.myDynamicField) }}
{% endif %}
```

You may also need to check if `form.myDynamicField` is not [null](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/null.html).

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is a few years old, but you could also make it a shorter ternary operator.

`{{ form.myDynamicField is defined ? form_row(form.myDynamicField) : null }}`

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_errors(form) }}

  {% if form.getChildren['myDynamicField'] is defined %}
    {{ form_row(form.myDynamicField) }}
  {% endif %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```